# SwiftUI not staying logged out

Tags: swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication

in my SwiftUI app, I have incorporated a login page. I have added a sign out button, which indeed takes you back to the login page, however, it is not staying logged out once I reopen the app.

Below is where the login page is.

```
**class AppViewModel:ObservableObject{
**    
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    
    @Published var signedIn = false
    
    var isSignedIn: Bool {
        return auth.currentUser != nil //not signed in
    }
    
    func signIn(email: String, password: String){
        auth.signIn(withEmail: email,
                    password: password){ [weak self] result, error in
            guard result != nil, error == nil else{
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                //Success
                self?.signedIn = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func signUp(email: String, password: String){
        auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password){[weak self] result, error in
            guard result != nil, error == nil else{
                return
            }
         //success
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                //Success
                self?.signedIn = true
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func signOut(){
        try? auth.signOut()
        
        self.signedIn = false
    }
    
}



**struct ContentView: View {
**    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            if viewModel.signedIn {
                    MainPage()
            }
            else{                
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            viewModel.signedIn = viewModel.isSignedIn
        }
    }
}

struct SignInView: View {
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Image("crest")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                
                VStack{
                    TextField("Email Address", text: $email)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                    
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else{
                            return
                        }
                        viewModel.signIn(email: email, password: password)
                    }, label: {
                            Text("Sign In")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                           })
                    
                    NavigationLink("Create Account", destination: SignUpView())
                }
                .padding()
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Sign In")
    }
}


struct SignUpView: View {
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Image("crest")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                
                VStack{
                    TextField("Email Address", text: $email)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                    
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else{
                            return
                        }
                        viewModel.signUp(email: email, password: password)
                    }, label: {
                            Text("Create Account")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                           })
                }
                .padding()
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Create Account")
        
    }
}
```

And then below is where I incorporated the sign out button (in a different view)

```
@EnvironmentObject var appViewModel: AppViewModel
....
Button {
                    appViewModel.signedIn = false
                } label: {
                   Text("Sign Out")
                }
```

This reloads the current view to the sign in page but does not stay there.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Tried messing around with contentView to see why the "signedIn" variable was not staying and did research revolving that.

Comment: You are overriding and eliminating any possibility of getting errors from firebase to see what is going on. Look at the Auth documentation done use `try?` use `do try catch` and use the provided listener to determine if the user is truly logged in or not. The way you code is now `FirebaseAuth` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the signOut method in the AppViewModel.

```
YourView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appViewModel: AppViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // NOT THIS: appViewModel.signedIn = false
            appViewModel.signOut()
        } label: {
            Text("Sign Out")
        }
    }
}
```

You are checking if there is a user session in the Firebase every time you open your app, and you are building your authentication logic on top of this. Making the signedIn property false does not sign the user out from Firebase. It is just your local variable.